# Number of iterations as a hyper-parameter in neural network

Tags: python, neural-network

How to determine what's the optimal number of iterations in learning a neural network?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is to split your training data into a train and validation set. During training, the error on the training set should decrease steadily. The error on the validation set will decrease and at some point start to increase again. At this point the net starts to overfit to the training data. What that means is that the model adapts to the random variations in the data rather than learning the true regularities. You should retain the model with overall lowest validation error. This is called [Early Stopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_stopping).
Alternatively, you can use [Dropout](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf). With a high enough Dropout probability, you can essentially train for as long as you want, and overfitting will not be a significant issue.